# How to export excel/csv in snap?

Tags: snap-lang

I have a list of numbers, how can I export to excel/csv/sheets?

In scratch I can right-click & "export", hoping snap has something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't (yet) a way to do this from the user interface. We are [working on it](https://github.com/jmoenig/Snap--Build-Your-Own-Blocks/pull/1670) though.

For the moment, you'll need to use a CSV export library, like [this one](http://snap.berkeley.edu/snapsource/snap.html#present:Username=jguille2&ProjectName=csv) by Joan Guillén.

To use it, create a variable (in this example, `csv text`) and run:

[image: CSV export script]

Then right click on the `csv text` variable watcher on the Stage and select `Export`:

[image: Export variable contents]

Hope it helps!

## EDIT

You can, since a while ago, right click on the list reporter and select export. Snap! will know that you're trying to export a list and will automatically use CSV as an export format:

[image: export as CSV]

If you hold the shift key while right-clicking on the list reporter, you'll be able to explicitly specify a format:

[image: export options]